# How to assign key from one variable to value in another, angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm rendering form on a page with help ng-repeat, data for this form comes dynamically from request. In this data I have nested array - categories. Inside of this array defined ids and list of this ids I can see in my form. From another request I get another array where defined names for ids. How can I assign key value from one variable to key value from another variable that display on the page list of names instead of list of ids

This is [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/WxLnmf9nv7BaDrayn991?p=preview) with my problem. I appreciate any help, thanks in advance.

html of my form

```
 <form style="padding: 15px" ng-submit="submitForm(rowData)">
            <div class="form-group row">
            <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in rowData">
            <div  ng-if="key | id">
                <label class="col-sm-6">{{key | makeUppercase}}</label>
                <div class=" col-sm-6">
                <input class="form-control rowValue"
                       id="rowData[key]"
                       ng-if="!isObject(value)"
                       type="text"
                       ng-model="rowData[key]"
                                                    />
               <span
                     class="form-control rowValue"
                     id="categories"
                     ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'categories'"
                     ng-model="rowData.categories">   
                        {{rowData.categories}}
                </span>
               </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            </div>
                 <div class="pull-right">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" 
               ng-if="rowData">Save</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-if="rowData"
               ng-click="cancelForm()">Cancel</button>
             </div>
         </form>
```

Comment: Please, what do you want to do ?

Comment: Why do you don't try something like ui-select plugin : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select

Comment: @AbdelrhmanMohamed I want to diaplay instead `[3,5,7]` value from other variable like `[Category 5,Category 1,Category 6]`

Comment: @GeraldChablowski I'm not trying to show all values, I just want to display names like `[Category 5,Category 1,Category 6]` instead of `[3,5,7]`

Comment: I understand but for doing that you will be oblige to wait for you other data to be recuperate and make an ng-repeat with it and it exist some all in one solution like ui-select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My implementation is very naive but it displays what you want.
I add this function to your controller

```
  $scope.getCategoryIns = function(ids){
    var categoriesName = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < ids.length; j ++){
    id = ids[j];
   for(var i= 0; i < $scope.categories.length;i++)
   {
      if ( $scope.categories[i].id == id){
        categoriesName.push($scope.categories[i].name);
      }
   }
 }

  var str = categoriesName.join(', ');
  return str;
}
```

and in HTML use this function as following

```
<span class="form-control rowValue"  id="categories" ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'categories'" ng-model="rowData.categories">
                       {{getCategoryIns(rowData.categories)}}</span>
```

[plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/frrnO70zkuw6s0BbJH58?p=options)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new method in your controller that maps the numbers in `$scope.rowData.categories` to `$scope.categories.id` and returns values of the corresponding category names:

```
$scope.getCategoryName = function (categoriesArr) {
    return categoriesArr.map(function(curr) {
        return $scope.categories.filter(function(el){
            return el.id === curr; //filter out the appropriate category by id
        })[0].name; //select the item and grab its name property
    })
}
```

and update your HTML to use the new method:

```
<span>
    class="form-control rowValue"
    id="categories"
    ng-if="isObject(value) && key == 'categories'"
    ng-model="rowData.categories">
     {{getCategoryName(rowData.categories)}}
</span>
```